# Why do adding and removing a class from a div onclick not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to do this: clicking a `>` to show a list and a `V`, click again to close the list and change `V` back to `>`. Here is my code

```js
function toggle() {

  var toggleClosed = $(this).find(".toggle-closed");
  var toggleOpened = $(this).find(".toggle-opened");

  if (!$(toggleClosed).is(":visible")) {
    toggleClosed.removeClass('toggle-opened').addClass('toggle-closed');
    toggleOpened.removeClass('toggle-closed').addClass('toggle-opened');
  } else {
    $(toggleClosed).addClass('toggle-closed').removeClass('toggle-opened');
    $(toggleOpened).addClass('toggle-opened').removeClass('toggle-closed');
  }
}
```

```css
.form-row-filter {
  background-color: grey;
}

.toggle-opened {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}

.toggle-closed {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}

.material-icons {
  margin-right: -4px;
  margin-left: 4px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-row-filter" style="display:inline-block">
  <ul>
    <div class="material-icons toggle-opened" onclick="toggle()">&gt;</div>
    <div class="material-icons toggle-closed" onclick="toggle()">V</div>
    <li class="toggle-closed">
      company a
    </li>
    <li class="toggle-closed">
      company b
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here is a codepen:

https://codepen.io/thinkvantagedu/pen/MNORvZ?editors=1100

Why wouldn't the class being added or removed?

Comment: It's because you're using an inline event handler, therefore `this` refers to the window, not the element which raised the event. Also, your HTML is invalid. You cannot have a `div` as a child of a `ul`. The latter point means you need to completely restructure the HTML, and then re-attempt the JS accordingly.

Comment: It looks like you are using the `toggle-opened` class to find your toggleClosed and toggleOpened elements.

But then inside your `toggle()` function you are adding/removing those same classes. This can result in unexpected behavior.

I would suggest using a separate class name (or an ID if possible) to target the elements you want to show/hide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your code fixed: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BXmgdo

The mistakes were in the JS:

```
function toggle () {

  var toggleClosed = $('.toggle-closed');
  var toggleOpened = $('.toggle-opened');

  toggleClosed.removeClass('toggle-closed').addClass('toggle-opened');
  toggleOpened.removeClass('toggle-opened').addClass('toggle-closed');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would probably only use jQuery's `toggleClass` in this situation.

As simple as:

```
$(".toggle-element").toggleClass("toggle-closed").toggleClass("toggle-opened");
```

You can use it for managing arrows too.
So, this is how I would do your `toggle` method:

```
function toggle () {
    $(".toggle-element").toggleClass("toggle-closed").toggleClass("toggle-opened");
    $(".toggle-trigger").toggleClass("closed");
}
```

Where `.toggle-trigger` class could contain different arrows based on `.closed` class.
You can even remove one of those classes completely.

```
$(".toggle-element").toggleClass("toggle-closed");
```

This would work just fine.

Here's an example:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JgOQax?editors=1100

And the code:

```js
  function toggle () {
    $(".toggle-element").toggleClass("toggle-closed");
    $(".toggle-trigger").toggleClass("closed");
}
```

```css
.form-row-filter {
  background-color: grey;
}
.toggle-closed {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}
.material-icons {
  margin-right: -4px;
  margin-left: 4px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.toggle-trigger::after{
  content: "v";
}
.toggle-trigger.closed::after{
  content: ">";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-row-filter" style="display:inline-block">
  <ul>
    <span class="material-icons toggle-trigger closed" onclick="toggle()"></span>
    <li class="toggle-element toggle-closed">
      company a
    </li>
    <li class="toggle-element toggle-closed">
      company b
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Aside from Rory's valid point about your HTML markup, the following should work. You'll want to replace all instances of `toggleme` with a name that is relevant to your elements, and unique from anything else in the document.

```js
$(".toggleme").click(function(){
  $(".toggleme").toggleClass("toggle-closed");
  $(".toggleme").toggleClass("toggle-opened");
})
```

```css
.toggle-opened {
  display: block;
}

.toggle-closed {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-row-filter" style="display:inline-block">
  <ul>
    <div class="material-icons toggle-opened toggleme">&gt;</div>
    <div class="material-icons toggle-closed toggleme">V</div>
    <li class="toggle-closed toggleme">
      company a
    </li>
    <li class="toggle-closed toggleme">
      company b
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```